# How do I tell whether this series is convergent or divergent?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

What do I do with this series:

$1 + \frac{\pi}{c} + \frac{\pi^2}{c^2} + \frac{\pi^3}{c^3} + ...$

I can rewrite it as: $\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} (\frac{\pi}{c})^n$

However, I have no clue what the value of c is. How do I tell whether it is convergent or divergent? If it is convergent, how would I figure out what the sum is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a geometric series so the value of c has to be greater than $\pi$ in absolute terms
The sum can be calculated with the formula $\frac{1}{1-r}$ with $r$ being $\frac{\pi}{c}$

Comment: So, it is safe to assume that c > $\pi$?

Comment: Put absolute value on the c, then you are good

Comment: Is there a specific reason that we are able to take such liberties in assuming such a thing? I believe you, I'm just curious on why we can assume this. (I'll be marking you answer as correct when it lets me).

Comment: Why may we assume $|c| > \pi$?  This criterion is nec. and suff. for convergence, but why may we just assume it?

Comment: A geometric series is convergent if |r|<1. That in itself can be proven as well, but I take that as a given. Any preCalc book has that derivation. So in essence, we want the absolute value of pi/c be less than 1 from which $c<-pi$ or $c>pi$ follows